# Возможно ли с помощью css сделать гармошку изображений?

Tags: css, css3

Вводная.
Есть блок фиксированного размера.
В блок нужно располагать разное количество изображений, одинаковых по размеру.
Если изображений мало, и они помещаются в блок, то должны следовать друг за другом (как в обычные inline-block).

Но вот если их становится больше, то они должны равномерно наезжать друг на друга, как бы уплотняясь (складываясь в стопку, как карты), и сохраняя свой исходный размер.

Возможно ли такое реализовать с помощью одного только css?

[image: Когда все помещаются] Пример когда inline-block.

[image: Когда места мало] Пример, когда места мало, и надо наложить.

Comment: Покажите пример того, как это должно выглядеть

Comment: @Cheg, поправил.

Comment: На скриншотах не особо чего разглядеть можно. Изображения должны в итоге не должны сжиматься?

Comment: @Cheg, да, всё верно. В этом всё и дело. Сжиматься не должны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то, например так:

```css
.gallery {
    display: flex;
}
.gallery > *:not(:last-child) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a3/4a/42/a34a424444743d1f982dd4557654c2b5--the-mountains-are-calling-idaho.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Здорово. Интересный ход :-) Спасибо.

Comment: способ неплох, но затирает соседние рисунки полностью. Это заметно, если у них есть альфаканал.

Comment: тогда внутри контейнера надо абсолютно по центру позиционировать и не скрывать. и последнему давать фикс ширину